# Double Entries in Async-Db-Requests

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

## The following Code gives 2 Entries, but at least one is expected.

```
 /// <inheritdoc />
  public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(Guid id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     where T : class
  {
     var entity = await Set<T>().FindAsync(new[] { id }, cancellationToken);

     return entity ?? throw new NotFoundException(typeof(T).Name, id);
  }
```

The given Entity is signed with a "single", so only one Entity is allowed to get back from the DB.

### Steps to reproduce

call GetAsync(model.Id, cancellationToken) to receive at least one data.
The Database Table contains only one Row, which should be returned.

### Further technical details

EF Core version: 3.0
Database provider: Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql
Target framework: .Net Core 3.0
Operating system: Mac OS
IDE: Rider

Comment: What do you mean it "gives" two entities? What does it mean that the entity is _" signed with a "single""_? What does `Set<T>()` do? Please read [ask] and provide a [mre], including all relevant information. [`DbSet<T>.FindAsync()` returns one of `T`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.findasync?view=efcore-2.1), so it's really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @shadowsfalling just answered it correct. But thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [DbSet.FindAsync(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.findasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) method.

In your case the `cancellationToken` was interpreted as the second item of the `params object[] keyValues` parameter.